# Cannot use AirDrop on my Mac running Yosemite

Tags: imac, airdrop

I am trying to use AirDrop to copy some files to my iPad Air 2 but have some problems.

In my AirDrop folder, it never asked me whether I want to share it with Contact or Everyone. I have my ipad AirDrop turned on but it does not appear on my Mac's AirDrop folder.

I have Wifi and Bluetooth turned on on both devices. This is what my AirDrop window looks like:

[image]

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: What Mac do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac may not meet the system requirements. At the bottom of [this page](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106), you'll see a list of the computers that support AirDrop.

(If your computer is one of the ones that should support AirDrop, please edit your question to say so.)